# How to play sound in ear speaker in xamarin android?

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm doing a cross platform app in visual studio, I want to know how to play sound in ear speaker, like mobile ringing sound while we make a call, can any one help me for this?

**UPDATE**
Actually I was trying to do SIP calling. I have used Android.Net.Sip. I can able to call to SIP Numbers but before pick the call from end user the ring sound cant be ringing in my mobile.

Its having this functions but I cant able hear ring sound

```
//Called when a RINGING response is received for the INVITE request sent.
public override void OnRingingBack(SipAudioCall call)
{
     base.OnRingingBack(call); 
}
```

for this I was tried to play ring sound using media player, but this will use loud speaker, for this I want to play ring sound in ear speaker or can we can able play ring sound using above functions. can any one help me for this?

Answer (score 1):

No need to restart your phone. Just close the running apps and try the audio. It'll be normal, through your main speaker. I've observed one thing. While the music is coming through ear speaker just make a call, that automatically pauses the playing audio, and in the call put on the loud speaker and now go to the music player (don't disconnect the call, let it go in speaker mode) and turn on the music, now the audio will get out through main speaker in normal way. Again putting off the speaker mode of the current going call throw back the audio to ear speaker. After disconnecting that call also the audio will play through ear speaker only. I don't know the reason behind this. This is just my observation. Finally I would like to conclude that, no need to restart your phone. Just close the running apps (all) and now try the audio. It'll be fine.